# How to stop ESS from asking for "R starting project directory"?

Tags: org-mode, ess

Every time I execute all code blocks in an org mode file that contains an R code block (using `org-babel-execute-buffer` with `C-c C-v C-b`), ESS pauses to ask for `R starting project directory`, which seems to default to the current directory of the `.org` file. This prompt causes delays as there is often lengthy initialization process and other code blocks before encountering the first R block. So one has to come back after a minute or two to make it continue.

My question is:

*Is there a way to disable the prompt for R starting project directory and always have it defaulted to the current directory?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set `ess-ask-for-ess-directory` to nil.  And, maybe, also check the value of `ess-startup-directory`, which should also be nil to use current buffer's default directory.