# File-local variable, stop emacs from asking for ess-starting-directory

Tags: ess, file-local-variables

I am trying to get ESS to stop asking for "R starting project directory".

I have seen this post: [How to stop ESS from asking for "R starting project directory"?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69059/how-to-stop-ess-from-asking-for-r-starting-project-directory), but it does not seem to work for me.

I have the following file local variable declarations in an org file:

`# -*- eval: (setq-local ess-startup-directory nil); ess-ask-for-ess-directory : nil -*-`

However when I try to export with R src blocks or even when I call `R` from the ESS package it still prompts me and defaults to suggesting the root of the current project.

What am I doing wrong?

To be clear, I have confirmed that the variables are being set correctly (both to nil) locally. Even when I try to set them globally I still get prompted with the default suggestion being the project root.

Comment: Not that this will change your outcome, but `# -*- eval: (setq-local ess-startup-directory nil); ess-ask-for-ess-directory : nil -*-` is surely a.k.a. `# -*- ess-startup-directory: nil; ess-ask-for-ess-directory: nil -*-` -- I cannot see any reason for an `eval` there.

Comment: Setting a buffer-local value which doesn't seem to be used often means the buffer in question isn't actually current at the time the variable is evaluated (it may be the buffer you *see* selected, but lisp code can be setting other buffers behind the scenes).  Based on the linked Q&A which *sounds* fair (but I don't use ESS/R) can you just confirm that when you "try to set them globally", `C-h v` is definitely reporting that the global value is the one you expected?